# Woocommerce REST API: Custom field instead of product name

Tags: php, api, rest, woocommerce

Is it possible to use custom field value for product name when using Woocommerce REST API?
I have added a key for DHL in REST API settings. Now I want to add a custom field on every product (it will be short names) so it will be used when sending API request for DHL, instead of original product names.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, why is this feature not in woocommerce from out of the box, this is crazy. EVERY company would need this.  every real company will need implement this as custom code by the looks.  no wonder my code developer friends tell me woocommerce is not a REAL store.

Comment: @50lmr did you find a solution from a year ago? there is still very little information out there for such a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a number of other developers with solutions for this on github, here is one, yes I know it is for secondary SKU, but it should be fairly trivial to modify it to cater for a secondary Product Name.

https://github.com/pmgarman/wc-international-sku

> Add a secondary SKU to products that is used for orders shipping
> outside of the base country of WooCommerce (international orders).
>
> == Description == Sometimes orders being shipped internationally require shipping a slightly different variation of your product (for
> various legal/regulatory reasons). This plugin will allow for products
> to have two SKUs, one for domestic orders and one for international
> orders. The SKU returned on order items in orders via the API and
> dashboard will be filtered to return the international SKU when the
> shipping address varies from the shop base address

Answer (score -1):

You can use the SKU field of the product.

WooCommerce API allows you to GET products via the SKU field for example - add to your GET products (without a product id) params &sku=DD1213 and your will receive said product - I don't recall if Woocommerce allows SKU duplicates but if it does... than don't! :)

So that means you can GET a product via SKU query example (PHP Curl):

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=somekind_of_key&consumer_secret=your_secret&sku=DD1213',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

This is only for the GET purposes - for updating and others you will need to use the product ID endpoint.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Basically, in Woo / Settings/ Advanced / REST API - I have added a key for DHL tracking. And its working fine. What I want is event/action to modify product name before it will be send to DHL service when user purchase product.

Comment: You mean, you would like to change the data sent to DHL only? as in add or edit product shortnames to the DHL tracker?

Comment: Yes. Before the data was sent to DHL I want to use custom field for shortnames and sent it instead of original product name.

Comment: Shlomtzion.  you mis-understand the question entirely. Perhaps you have never run a store with dhl international shipping.  DHL actually calls the Rest API to get your daily orders, its called import orders, and dhl runs the background job on their side every 20 minutes automatically. dhl calls the wp/wc rest API seeing if you have new orders sold, and reads all address and all products, the question is how do you change the product name so that it is a name suitable for shipping customs declarations.  the wc product name would NEVER be suitable for shipping, therefore WC is substandard.